# Show interstitial ad once every 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been struggling dealing with ads and their frequency capping lately.
I'm using Adform (an advertising platform) and I've been demanded to create an interstitial ad for mobile visitor in a way that it should show only once every X minutes. (Getting an interstitial ad each time you read another post on site is annoying).

So far I've been using a premade script and it works fine with img and table tags but not with the script itself!
Here's the script used so far:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Frequency Cap Content script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* Please keep this notice intact
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

//["ID of content to frequency cap", "Display frequency interval (full hours only)"]
var capcontent=new Array()
capcontent[0]=["myad", "1 hr"]
capcontent[1]=["mynote", "3 hr"]

function get_cookie(Name) {
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1)
end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}

function resetcookie(id){
var expireDate = new Date()
expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours()-10)
document.cookie = id+"=;path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
}

function showorhide(caparray){
if (get_cookie(caparray[0])!='')
document.write("#"+caparray[0]+"{display: none;}\n") //CSS TO HIDE CONTENT BTW FREQUENCY
else{
var expireDate = new Date()
expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours()+parseInt(caparray[1]))
document.cookie = caparray[0]+"="+parseInt(caparray[1])+";path=/;expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
}
}

document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')

for (i=0; i<capcontent.length; i++){
if (get_cookie(capcontent[i][0])!=parseInt(capcontent[i][1]))
resetcookie(capcontent[i][0])
showorhide(capcontent[i])
}

document.write('</style>')

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myad">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adx.adform.net/adx/?mid=303469&rnd=%%ADFRND%%"></script>


</div>

<div id="table">

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

As you might notice, inside the div with id "myad" I've inserted the javascript code. If I open the site, the ad shows up,but once closed and reloaded the page, it stil keeps showing up!

Any help please?

Comment: I see nothing php related, removing the tag

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use this code:

```
    function showInterstitial() {
    if ($.cookie("IntersCookie") == null) {
        $.cookie("IntersCookie", "1", {
            path: ".mydomain.com",
            expires: 1
        });

    }
}
```

Try it!

Comment: Unforntunately I don't understand that code that much!
Where should I put my script in there?!

Comment: first of all, try to put your script at the end of the body.